# Table Row not showing correctly

Tags: html, html-table

Why is the 5th row not taking any effect ?

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="300">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">4</td>
    <td colspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

[image: Expected Output]

I expect total row should be 5 as the attached image.

Answer (score 1):

You just need some more content to see the effect of your rowspans. If you leave all cells (almost) empty, they will take only the minimum space they need for their contents to fit. `td` sizes are dynamic, they adjust automatically and always (also) depend on their contents:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="300">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">4 you need some more content to see the effect of your rowspans</td>
    <td colspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks ....  You just  c leared   my  hours  of  frustration.